# Should "afford" be transitive in "my chosen path has afforded (to) me unique opportunities"?

Tags: word-choice, verbs, transitivity

In a college essay I wrote a sentence that reads:

> Sixteen years later, my chosen path has afforded to me unique opportunities, limitless learning, and potential for growth.

Should I use the verb *offered* or *afforded*? After that, should I use *to me*, or *me*?

Comment: _Afford_ is transitive in all its senses. Your question title, as stated, makes no sense. BTW, _afford_ has indirect object _me_ and direct object _unique ... growth_, and has undergone Dative Movement here, so there should be no _to_. Just like _He gave me the ball_ instead of _*He gave to me the ball._

Comment: @JohnLawler - John, I found this explanation of dative alternation (http://www.glottopedia.org/index.php/Dative_alternation), and, if I understand it correctly, the OP's questions fits the PP NP form. But in that explanation it also says "PP NP structures though regarded as ungrammatically can seldom be found." This looks like a misprint, but my question is should it say "grammatical" or "ungrammatical"? (Or maybe I misunderstand the article.)

Comment: I have no idea what the author might have meant. The Dative Alternation has two alternate forms in simple cases: `Vb` + `IO` + `DO`, and `Vb` + `DO` + _to_ `IO`. Only the second form is allowed when the `DO` is a pronoun (i.e, _Give it to him_ but not  _*Give him it._) The first form has, as noted, no _to_ marking the  `IO`.

Answer (score 1):

*Afforded me* is proper. Yours has no grammaticality, alas; so your title is ungrammatical.

Your chosen path could have *provided* (you with...); *given* (you...); *granted* (you with); *guided* (you to...); *cleared way* (to...); *brought* (you to...); *paved the way* (for...); and plenty more. Though the one you chose is erroneous in its nature!

Answer (score 0):

You should just use me, as in *afforded me*. Afford in this sense means to provide.

Answer (score 0):

This is correct:

My path currently affords me unique and limitless learning opportunities with potential for growth in the area(s) of [list area(s)].

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hello Kate. OP has apparently not returned for almost a year, and the answers above were adequate.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is transitive. So,

> *...[H]as afforded me unique opportunities....*

[The Free Dictionary-Collins Complete and Unabridged](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/afford)

> 2. to give, yield, or supply: *the meeting afforded much useful information*